# how to make text on label in center in sencha touch

Tags: html, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am Working with Sencha touch application. 
I have added Ext.label as component on which i display dynamic text of different length. 
i can made this text horizontally center in size of label component, but it cant't centered vertically. 
in short,i want to display my dynamic text of different length in middle of label component. 
any help will be appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Use CSS's line-height property set to the height of your label to make it vertically centered.

Comment: Did my answer help you out?

Answer (score 0):

If your height is static use padding;
If it is not static put your label in a container with a layout set to vertical and add a spacer on top and under the label.Set the flex to 1 for each spacer and keep the flex undefined on the label.

Normally, it would center the label,but you might need to add a minimal height value to the label.

The spacers should take the remaining space available and split it in two which would therefore center the label in the container at all time. The container could be a new class on which you add a setLabel() function and this class could be somekind of superLabel.